# Setting line color by 'hue' in Seaborn line plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am making a faceted line plot in seaborn, where each subgrid has two lines, one where DATA = 'fitted' and another where DATA = 'original'. I want them to be plotted in different colors.  I've tried setting palette = to my chosen palette, but they still both print as blue.  How can I choose which color each line is displayed as?

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

palette = sns.color_palette("hls", 2)

g = sns.FacetGrid(comboSites, col="SITE", hue="DATA", palette=palette, col_wrap=3)
g.map(sns.lineplot, "YEAR","NDVI", "SITE")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Imports and DataFrame

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

comboSites = pd.DataFrame({"SITE": np.repeat(np.repeat(['AT02', 'BA01', 'BA02'], 2), 21),
                           "DATA": np.repeat(np.tile(['original', 'fitted'], 3), 21),
                           "YEAR": np.tile(np.arange(2000, 2021), 6),
                           "NDVI": np.random.randint(-200, 800, 6 * 21)})
palette = sns.color_palette("hls", 2)
```

### Since `seaborn v0.11.0`

- It is now recommended to use figure-level methods like `seaborn.relplot` instead of `seaborn.FacetGrid`.

```py
g = sns.relplot(data=comboSites, col="SITE", hue="DATA", palette=palette,
                col_wrap=3, x='YEAR', y='NDVI', kind='line', height=3)
```

### Before `seaborn v0.11.0`

You are giving three parameters to [`sns.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html).  The first will be used for `x` ('YEAR'), the second for `y` ('NDVI') and the third for `hue` ('SITE'). That way, the hue of the `FacetGrid` won't be used. Leaving out that third parameter will lead to the desired plot.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(comboSites, col="SITE", hue="DATA", palette=palette, col_wrap=3)
g.map(sns.lineplot, "YEAR", "NDVI")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

### Output

[image: facet grid with two lines]